# Nested groups in active directory and permissions?

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group

Here are some groups and permissions that apply to a user named ALI.

[image: diagram of groups and permissions for user ALI]

These are simple groups created in Active directory. Will ALI receive Full Control or Read Only permissions??